# Wpf DataGrid Column splitting

Tags: wpf, datagridcolumn

I want to put a column to specify range in a wpf datagrid.
For this, i am thinking to take one column with header "Range" and i want to split that into 2 columns like "Minimum" and "Maximum".
Is it possible to represent data like that?
If it is, what about the data binding to the datagrid means how binding will change?

Comment: why not just have two colums representing two field of a class named max and minima....besides you can't divide a column in parts since it's already a parted element of a row

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep you min/max parts non-resizable, then a fairly simple solution exists:

1. In your objects create a property of Tuple type or whatever type will represent your min/max structure.
2. Add a templated column to your grid as follows (sample bindings should work with the Tuple I didn't try it though):

---

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Min/Max">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Item1}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Item2}" />
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

Bind your grid to the data as normal