# Split the column of datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridheaderborder

[image]I have a datagrid in my form which has columns for each of Question Types.
I want that column to be split into two as i want to accept number of compulsory and number of optional questions for each of the question type in the subsequent columns.

I have achieved this in winforms, thanks to stackoverflow.com.

I am trying to achieve the same in WPF

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the similar post here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090974/wpf-datagrid-column-splitting

Comment: Please post a screenshot of UI on the question. I am quite not understand what do you want to do.

Comment: I tried to post the screen shot of the same which i had done in winforms, but as I'm new to stackoverflow, I need at least 10 reputation to upload the image.

Comment: After a lot of try, I gave up the idea of splitting the columns and used the StackPanel and ScrollViewer concept. Again thanks to all for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the `DataGrid` layout you want.... right?

```
.------.-----------------.--------.
|      |   ID Details    |        |
| Name |-----------------| Status |
|      | ID   | Passport |        |
|------|------|----------|--------|
|X     | 123  | E567868  | Present|
|Y     | 236  | 7875678  | Absent |
'------'------'----------'--------'
```

WPF datagrid doesnt support this readily. But you can do some **stretchy** coding. The code like below can split the headers. You need to take caution that ...

> When the split columns are reordered (`DataGrid.ColumnReordered`
>   event), all the sibling columns       under their common parent header should be
>   moved, together. I am leaving that code to you.

Have some custom **styles** for `DataGridHeaders`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}" 
  x:Key="SplitHeaderStyle">
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Controls:DataGridHeaderBorder 
            SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}"
            IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
            IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
            IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Padding ="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}"
            SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}">
            <ContentPresenter 
            Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                      Path=Content[0]}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Controls:DataGridHeaderBorder>
            <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Controls:DataGridHeaderBorder
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            IsClickable="False"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Padding ="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
            SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}">
            <ContentPresenter 
                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                          Path=Content[1]}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                Margin="-8,2,-10,2"/>
            </Controls:DataGridHeaderBorder>
            <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftSplitHeaderGripper"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
            Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}" 
   BasedOn="{StaticResource SplitHeaderStyle}"
   x:Key="SplitHeaderLeftStyle">
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
<Setter Property="Tag" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}" 
   BasedOn="{StaticResource SplitHeaderStyle}"
   x:Key="SplitHeaderRightStyle">
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
<Setter Property="Tag" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
</Style>
```

Have columns arranged like this...

```
<Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
<Controls:DataGridTextColumn 
         Header="Name" 
         Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
<Controls:DataGridTextColumn 
         Binding="{Binding ID}" 
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource SplitHeaderRightStyle}">
    <Controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="System:String">
        <System:String>ID</System:String>
        <System:String>ID De</System:String>                            
    </x:ArrayExtension>
    </Controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</Controls:DataGridTextColumn>
<Controls:DataGridTextColumn 
         Binding="{Binding Passport}"
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource SplitHeaderLeftStyle}">
    <Controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="System:String">
        <System:String>Passport</System:String>
        <System:String>tails</System:String>                            
    </x:ArrayExtension>
    </Controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</Controls:DataGridTextColumn>
<Controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Status"
            Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
  </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

**So basically you use the same default header layout of `DataGrid` but hack it in a way that two headers *look* like they are joined together.**

**C#**

1. Name your `DataGrid` e.g. `x:Name="MyDataGrid"`.
2. Keep all the styles in XAML in `<DataGrid.Resources ..>` tag. Make sure that they have `x:Key` set. e.g. `x:Key="SplitHeaderLeftStyle"` & `x:Key="SplitHeaderRightStyle"`

   ```
   <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style 
                 TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}" 
                 x:Key="SplitHeaderStyle" .../>

            <Style x:Key="SplitHeaderLeftStyle" 
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource SplitHeaderStyle}".../>

            <Style x:Key="SplitHeaderRightStyle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource SplitHeaderStyle}" .../>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        ...
   </DataGrid>
   ```
3. in your C# code when you add columns, set the styles by their `Key`.

   ```
     var dgIDColumn 
       = new DataGridTextColumn()
         {
           Header = new string[] { "ID", "ID Det" },
           Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("ID") },
           HeaderStyle = MyDataGrid.FindResource("SplitHeaderRightStyle") as Style;
         };

    MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(dgIDColumn);

     var dgPassportColumn 
      = new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
           Header = new string[] { "Passport", "ails" },
           Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Passport") },
           HeaderStyle = MyDataGrid.FindResource("SplitHeaderLeftStyle") as Style;
        };

     MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(dgPassportColumn);
   ```

Comment: Oh that's really great... It works absolutely fine... I appreciate it... But my problem is still not solved as I have to do the same thing programmatically...

Comment: You mean C# code? Templates \ Styles are very difficult to tame in C#. I am afraid the best you can do is create them in XAML and refer them by their `x:Key`.

Comment: oh... can you give me an example?? I'm very new to WPF

Comment: The solution is really helpful, but can you please tell how we can implement this for multilingual column headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Question1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Compulsory" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Optional Q" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question.Col1}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question.Col2}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. But my problem is different. The question types are loaded based on the value in the database. And hence I want to split the column programmatically.

Comment: I mean can you use a Grid instead of a DataGrid? it provides more freedom because it's more general. and with a bit more of work it provides what you need.

Comment: I don't know if that can be an option. As there is no fixed number of columns in the datagrid.

Comment: There is a way to bind the number of rows and columns of a grid. look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000549/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate

Comment: I've added another answer with more explanations

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Row/Column/ColumnSpan/RowSpan in DataTriggers of ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle to your liking.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cells}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid 
                local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding NumOfColumns}"
                local:GridHelpers.AutoColumns="0,1"
                local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding NumOfRows}"
                local:GridHelpers.AutoRows="0,1">
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=RowIndex}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnIndex}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CellType}" Value="BaseCell">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BaseCell}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnSpan}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CellType}" Value="CornerHeader">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CornerHeader}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CellType}" Value="PersonNameCell">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PersonNameCell}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                ...
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

I've added AutoColumns property to GridHelper class which is explained in [this link](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/)

```
    #region AutoColumns Property

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes the specified Column's Width equal to Auto. 
    /// Can set on multiple Columns
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AutoColumns", typeof(string), typeof(GridHelpers),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, AutoColumnsChanged));

    // Get
    public static string GetAutoColumns(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(AutoColumnsProperty);
    }

    // Set
    public static void SetAutoColumns(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AutoColumnsProperty, value);
    }

    // Change Event - Makes specified Column's Width equal to Auto
    public static void AutoColumnsChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(obj is Grid) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValue.ToString()))
            return;

        SetAutoColumns((Grid)obj);
    }

    private static void SetAutoColumns(Grid grid)
    {
        string[] autoColumns = GetAutoColumns(grid).Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (autoColumns.Contains(i.ToString()))
                grid.ColumnDefinitions[i].Width = GridLength.Auto;
        }
    }

    private static void SetAutoRows(Grid grid)
    {
        string[] autoRows = GetAutoRows(grid).Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (autoRows.Contains(i.ToString()))
                grid.RowDefinitions[i].Height = GridLength.Auto;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```